# All wix hosted images ( image url ) don't show on mobile version but work perfect on desktop? How to proceed?

Tags: html, image, url, mobile, velo

Just published my site. Used plenty of links from images hosted on other websites. 
ALL the pictures open just perfect on desktop but on mobile version all wix hosted images don't show, it shows the text "reponsive image" in a txtbx on the mobile version. ... How to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Wix img url are not mobile responsive.